# Docker swarm replicas on different nodes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using a docker-compose file version 3 with its deploy key to run a swarm (docker version 1.13) and I would like to replicate a service in order to make it resilient again single node failure.

However, when I'm adding a deploy section like this:

```
deploy:
    replicas: 2
```

in my four node cluster I sometimes end up with both replicas scheduled on the same node. What I'm missing is a constraint that schedules the two instances on different nodes.

I know that there's a `global` mode I could use but that would run an instance on every node, i.e. four instances in my case instead of just two.

Is there a simple way to specify this constraint in a generic way without having to resort to a combination of `global` and a labels to keep additional instances away from?

Edit: After trying it again I find containers to be scheduled on different nodes this time around. I'm beginning to wonder if I may have had a `'node.hostname == X'` constraint in place.

Edit 2: After another service update - and without any placement constraints - the service is again being scheduled on the same node (as displayed by [ManoMarks Visualizer](https://github.com/ManoMarks/docker-swarm-visualizer)):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`docker/cli` PR 1612](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1612) seems to resolve [issue 26259](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26259), and has been released in [docker 19.03](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#19030).

> Added new switch `--replicas-max-per-node` switch to docker service
>
> ### How to verify it
>
> Create two services and specify `--replicas-max-per-node` one of them:
>
> ```
> docker service create --detach=true --name web1 --replicas 2 nginx
> docker service create --detach=true --name web2 --replicas 2 --replicas-max-per-node 1 nginx
> ```
>
> See difference on command outputs:
>
> ```
> $ docker service ls
> ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS               IMAGE               PORTS
> 0inbv7q148nn        web1                replicated          2/2                    nginx:latest        
> 9kry59rk4ecr        web2                replicated          1/2 (max 1 per node)   nginx:latest
>
> $ docker service ps --no-trunc web2
> ID                          NAME                IMAGE                                                                                  NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR                                                     PORTS
> bf90bhy72o2ry2pj50xh24cfp   web2.1              nginx:latest@sha256:b543f6d0983fbc25b9874e22f4fe257a567111da96fd1d8f1b44315f1236398c   limint              Running             Running 34 seconds ago                                                             
> xedop9dwtilok0r56w4g7h5jm   web2.2              nginx:latest@sha256:b543f6d0983fbc25b9874e22f4fe257a567111da96fd1d8f1b44315f1236398c                       Running             Pending 35 seconds ago   "no suitable node (max replicas per node limit exceed)"
> ```

The error message would be:

```
no suitable node (max replicas per node limit exceed)
```

Examples from [Sebastiaan van Stijn](https://github.com/thaJeztah):

> Create a service with max 2 replicas:
>
> ```
> docker service create --replicas=2 --replicas-max-per-node=2 --name test nginx:alpine
> docker service inspect --format '{{.Spec.TaskTemplate.Placement.MaxReplicas}}' test
> 2
> ```
>
> Update the service (max replicas should keep its value)
>
> ```
> docker service update --replicas=1 test
> docker service inspect --format '{{.Spec.TaskTemplate.Placement.MaxReplicas}}' test
> 2
> ```
>
> Update the max replicas to 1:
>
> ```
> docker service update --replicas-max-per-node=1 test
> docker service inspect --format '{{.Spec.TaskTemplate.Placement.MaxReplicas}}' test
> 1
> ```
>
> And reset to 0:
>
> ```
> docker service update --replicas-max-per-node=0 test
> docker service inspect --format '{{.Spec.TaskTemplate.Placement.MaxReplicas}}' test
> 0
> ```

Answer (score 17):

Extending [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57187144/2636418) answer, and as in your example you are using a compose file, not the cli, you could add `max_replicas_per_node: 1`, as in

```
version: '3.8'
...
yourservice:
    deploy:
          replicas: 2
          placement:
            max_replicas_per_node: 1
```

The compose schema version `3.8` is key here, as there is no support for max_replicas_per_node below `3.8`.

This was added in https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1410

Answer (score 1):

What version of docker are you using? According to this post in 1.13 this kind of problem has been rectified, do take a look: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26259#issuecomment-260899732

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that – 1.13 was the version I was using.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that issue - it seems like it's still open though. Linked from that issue is a work-around suggesting to add a dummy host port: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26259#issuecomment-277716832 I guess that would work but it feels a bit "hacky".

Comment: After trying it again I find containers to be scheduled on different nodes this time around. I'm beginning to wonder if I may have had a 'node.hostname == X' constraint in place. Possibly a non-issue then!

Comment: I am using Docker 18.03 and are still experiencing the problem. And I don't have any placement constraints for that particular service. I will probably try the dummy host port hack.